# Java Spring 4.0 responds with status code 200 but angular Js execute(to incorrect login) the error block of the response

Tags: mysql, angularjs, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPmaa.png)Angular js-1 (loginCtrl) : Angular doesn't reflect spring response, I do not understand what could be the problem...may you please assist, by the way am new to angular and spring RestFul-ws

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope,$http,$window){  

            $scope.login = function(email,password) {
            var myData = {
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password
            };

            $http.post(customerURL,JSON.stringify(myData)).then(function(response){
                if(response.data)
                console.log(response.data);
                $scope.msg = "SUCCESSFULLY LOGGED IN";
                $scope.status = response.status;
                $scope.statusText = response.statusText;
                console.log($scope.msg);    
                },function(response){
                 //console.log(response.status);

                $scope.msg = "ERROR LOGIN IN";

               console.log($scope.msg);


            });
        };                                                                                                       
       });
```

Java Spring 4.0 : find email and hashed password(using checkpw) correctly ...

```
 @RequestMapping(value="",method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public ResponseEntity LoginCustomer(@RequestBody String json) throws CustomerNotFoundException
     {
       try {
             ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
             final JsonNode data = mapper.readTree(json);

             String email = data.get("email").asText();
             String password = data.get("password").asText();


             if(services.findByName(email)  != null && services.findByPw(password) != null){
             logger.info("received correct user details in :json String " + json);
             System.out.println("Successfull!!");
             return  new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);

             }else{
              System.out.println("Error!!");
              return  new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
             }
        } catch (IOException ex){
         throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

     }
```

my current customer controller...

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.product.Controller;

import com.product.Exceptions.CustomerNotFoundException;
import com.product.Services.CustomerServices;
import com.product.Product.Customer;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCrypt;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/*
 *
 * @author HP
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController{
    /////////members ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerController.class);           //
     @Autowired                                                                                        //
     private CustomerServices services; 
     private BCryptPasswordEncoder pe;//
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

     @RequestMapping(value="",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
     public ResponseEntity createCustomer(@RequestBody String json) throws CustomerNotFoundException
     {
       try {
             ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
             final JsonNode data = mapper.readTree(json);
             logger.info("recived json String " + json);
             String email = data.get("email").asText();
             String password = data.get("password").asText();
             String firstname = data.get("firstname").asText();
             String surname = data.get("surname").asText();

             //brypt hashing 
             String pw_hash = BCrypt.hashpw(password,BCrypt.gensalt(10));

              Customer c = new Customer(firstname, surname, email, pw_hash);


             ///////create customer /////////
             services.createCustomer(c);
             ///return if try was succesful
             //loginService.createLogin(u);
            return  new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);

        } catch (IOException ex){
         throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

     }

     @RequestMapping(value="",method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public ResponseEntity LoginCustomer(@RequestBody String json) throws CustomerNotFoundException
     {
       try {
             ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
             final JsonNode data = mapper.readTree(json);

             String email = data.get("email").asText();
             String password = data.get("password").asText();


             if(services.findByName(email)  != null && services.findByPw(password) != null){
             logger.info("received correct user details in :json String " + json);
             System.out.println("Successfull!!");
             return  new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);

             }else{
              System.out.println("Error!!");
              return  new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
             }
        } catch (IOException ex){
         throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

     }



      @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> getAllCustomers() {

        List<Customer> customerList = services.getCustomerList();
        if(customerList != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(customerList, HttpStatus.OK);
        }else{
            return  new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<CustomerController> Delete(@PathVariable long id) throws CustomerNotFoundException {
    services.DeleteCustomer(id);
    return  new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: what response did you get?

Answer (score 0):

use bellow annotation before controller class :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
```

use before class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity save(@RequestBody LoginView loginView) {


}
```

and `LoginView` is a class which contain the same variable which use into JSON and its setter getter methods.

```
package com.test;



public class LoginView  {


private String email;

private String password;

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank your for time, those of you who went through my post, The post is of clear for sound, for I was able to solve this issue , the ultimate issue was that, the status code was always resorting to 200 even when url didn't exist, I prevented default and propagation in the client side, that stopped request from being cancelled... hope this helps someone, By the way this is my first Restful app ...I am the happiest person on earth... ;)